# Model coming through as null in controller

Tags: .net-core, umbraco

I have a relatively simple form that's posting to a controller, yet the model is coming through as null every time and I don't understand why. I'm using Umbraco CMS (so please ignore any Umbraco references if they're not relevant) and jquery combined with an image plugin (Filepond) to post the data. This is my model:

```
public class PropertyViewModel: PublishedContentWrapped
    {
        public PropertyViewModel(IPublishedContent content, IPublishedValueFallback publishedValueFallback) : base(content, publishedValueFallback)
        {
            this.Countries = GetCountries();
        }        

        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one image")]
        public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }        

        public SelectList Countries { get; set; }

        public SelectList GetCountries()
        {
            List<string> countryNames = Bia.Countries.Iso3166.Countries.GetAllActiveDirectoryNames();
            var countries = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var country in countryNames)
                countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = country, Value = country });

            return new SelectList(countries, "Text", "Value");
        }
    }
```

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateUmbracoFormRouteString]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleAddProperty(PropertyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }

    // Carry on execution..
}
```

Finally, here is my view. I should mention that model is a new instance of the PropertyViewModel class:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<PropertySurfaceController>("HandleAddProperty", null, new { @id = "form-add" }))
    {        
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
         <div class="mb-3">
            <select asp-for="@Model.Country" asp-items="Model.Countries" class="form-select">
                <option value="">Select country</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Country" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>         
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.DisplayName" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.DisplayName" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DisplayName" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Summary" class="form-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="@Model.Summary" class="form-control" aria-required="true"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Summary" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control" aria-required="true"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">            
            <input type="file" class="filepond" id="file" name="filepond" multiple data-max-file-size="5MB" data-max-files="10" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        
    }

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(e){
                FilePond.registerPlugin(
                    FilePondPluginImageResize,
                    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize
                );
    
                var pond = FilePond.create(
                    document.querySelector('#file'), {
                        allowMultiple: true,
                        instantUpload: false,
                        allowProcess: false,
                        imageResizeTargetWidth: 1280,
                        imageResizeUpscale: false,
                        imageResizeMode: 'contain'
                    });
    
                $("#form-add").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formdata = new FormData(this);
                    
                    // append FilePond files into the form data
                    var pondFiles = pond.getFiles();
                    for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
                        formdata.append('Images', pondFiles[i].file);
                    }
    
                    console.log('formdata', formdata);
    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/umbraco/surface/PropertySurface/HandleAddProperty",
                        data: formdata,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        method:"post"
                        }).done(function (response) {
                            // todo                        
                        });
     
                })
            });
        </script>
```

When I inspect in Chrome to see what data is being sent to the server I can see the following:

[image]

So I can see the fields are matching the model, yet it's still coming through as null. I can't figure out where it's failing.

I've tried using [FromBody] and [FromForm] with the controller parameter, but it made no difference.

Is anyone able to spot where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second parameter in BeginUmbracoForm is supposed to be the model, not null. So:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<PropertySurfaceController>("HandleAddProperty", new { @id = "form-add" })) 
{ ... }
```